# Sum the frequency for items that present in alternate columns

Tags: r, shell, awk

There are certain part of my data that I would like to further analyse on. The extracted information contained comparison between two items in separate columns and the frequency for each comparison. The order between the two columns in the table were not important.

Extracted info file (input file):

| Name1 | Name2 | Freq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Micractinium | Parachlorella | 588 |
| Parachlorella | Planktochlorella | 32 |
| Planktochlorella | Parachlorella | 78 |

Expected output:
Frequency of each comparison with no duplicate

| Name1 | Name2 | Freq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Micractinium | Parachlorella | 588 |
| Parachlorella | Planktochlorella | 110 |

I wanted to check the frequency of each comparison but problem arose when the comparison was duplicated as in the 2nd and 3rd row in the input file, where the comparisons involved the same name, but were in alternate columns.

I was processing the file using shellscript in Linux environment and in Excel initially, and trying to sort each row according to alphabetical order but it doesn't work, not sure what is the problem though.

Referred from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16175073/sort-each-line-in-a-text-file) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/447420/how-to-sort-by-row-from-terminal):

```
cat file | while read line; do echo $line | sed 's/\t/\n/g' | sort | gawk '{line=line " " $0} END {print line}' ; done
```

,

```
while read line; do 
      sorted=$(sort -g -- <<< "${line//[, ]/$'\n'}")
      printf -- "${sorted//$'\n'/,}\n"
    done < file
```

Then I tried to compile it manually but it is too time consuming to do it one by one. The list were up to 500 rows.

Wondering if this kind of task can better executed using R? I can use a bit of R, though not very familiar. Is there any function in R, that can save some time in this process? Or any other idea/suggestion other than R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In R, you can sort the names in `Name1` and `Name2` and `sum` the `Freq` value.

```
aggregate(Freq~Name1 + Name2, 
        transform(df, Name1 = pmin(Name1, Name2),  Name2 = pmax(Name1, Name2)), 
        sum, na.rm = TRUE)

#          Name1            Name2 Freq
#1  Micractinium    Parachlorella  588
#2 Parachlorella Planktochlorella  110
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Name1 = c("Micractinium", "Parachlorella","Planktochlorella"
), Name2 = c("Parachlorella", "Planktochlorella", "Parachlorella"
), Freq = c(588L, 32L, 78L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 3):

An `igraph` option

```
library(igraph)
setNames(
    get.data.frame(
        simplify(
            graph_from_data_frame(df, directed = FALSE),
            edge.attr.comb = "sum"
        )
    ),
    names(df)
)
```

gives

```
          Name1            Name2 Freq
1  Micractinium    Parachlorella  588
2 Parachlorella Planktochlorella  110
```

Comment: Nice use case of `igraph` , +1

Comment: @AnilGoyal Thanks. Your answer is nice as well, upvoted already!

Answer (score 2):

Even I would have also done it using `pmin` and `pmax`

```r
df <- structure(list(Name1 = c("Micractinium", "Parachlorella","Planktochlorella"
), Name2 = c("Parachlorella", "Planktochlorella", "Parachlorella"
), Freq = c(588L, 32L, 78L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))



library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)
df %>% group_by(Name_1 = pmin(Name1, Name2), Name_2 = pmax(Name1, Name2)) %>%
  summarise(across('Freq', sum), .groups = 'drop')
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   Name_1        Name_2            Freq
#>   <chr>         <chr>            <int>
#> 1 Micractinium  Parachlorella      588
#> 2 Parachlorella Planktochlorella   110
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

With `awk` you can do this in a single line.

```sh
awk '$1<$2{a[$1FS$2]+=$3;next;}{a[$2FS$1]+=$3;} END{for (key in a){print key,a[key]}}' input.txt
```

More Readable format below

```sh
awk '$1 < $2 {
    a[$1 FS $2] += $3
    next
}

{
    a[$2 FS $1] += $3
}

END {
    for (key in a) {
        print key, a[key]
    }
}' input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, sum),.(Name_1 = pmin(Name1, Name2),
       Name_2 = pmax(Name1, Name2)), .SDcols = patterns("Freq")]
```

-oputut

```
    Name_1           Name_2 Freq
1:  Micractinium    Parachlorella  588
2: Parachlorella Planktochlorella  110
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Name1 = c("Micractinium", "Parachlorella", "Planktochlorella"
), Name2 = c("Parachlorella", "Planktochlorella", "Parachlorella"
), Freq = c(588L, 32L, 78L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```